# API - Next.js Javascript object method to encode or decode to base64

Tags: javascript, api, next.js

I'm writing an API and I need to allow requests that include a string in the URL like:

`...://domain.org?encode=string_to_encode`
`...://domain.org?decode=base64_encoded_ASCII_to_decode`

I'm writing the API in JavaScript using Next.js and I have this so far:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResonse } from 'next';
export default (req, res) => {
  *PSEUDOCODE*
   if (URL includes 'encode') {
    res.status(200).json(result_of_fu)nction encode)
    } else {
    res.status(404)
}
   if (URL includes 'decode') {
    res.status(200).json(result_of_function decode)
   } else {
   res.status(404)
}
}
  })
}

let encode = (data) => {
   this.data = atob(data);
return data
}

let decode = (base64Data) => {
  this.base64Data = btoa(base64Data);
return base64Data
}
```

My question is, how do I handle the incoming request? I know I can parse the information from the URL and run a fuction in an object and return that in JSON to the res. But my question is what would that look like?

I haven't actually gotten the implementation down. I'm new to JavaScript, still learning! Any help would be so greatly appreciated! Have a great day!